# Insert label center of dashed line between two nodes with let

Tags: tikz-pgf

I know that is a simple question. But I could not solve it based on the topics that I found. Suppose we have two nodes \p1 and \p2 and a dashed line between it.

```
%custom colors
\definecolor{colorw_1}{RGB}{64,221,168}
\definecolor{colorw_2}{RGB}{255,170,34}
\definecolor{colorw_4}{RGB}{34,175,236}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw [white] (-4.1,-1.1) rectangle (4.5,1.4); %create a bounding box to reserve space
            \begin{pgflowlevelscope}{\pgftransformscale{0.82}}
            \matrix [matrix of nodes,row sep=0mm,
            set common column={2,...,11}{nodes={rectangle,draw,minimum width=2.65em, minimum height=1.90em}},
            set common row={0,9}{nodes={draw=none}},
            ] (O)
                {
                    $\ V \ \ $         & 1         & 2         & 3         & 4         & 5         & 6         & 7         & 8         & 9         & 10        \\ [2.5mm]
                    $\widetildeto{v}{\vartheta_{3}}$         & 0.12         & 0.89        & 0.38         & 0.96         & 0.43         & 0.66         & 0.49         & 0.81         & 0.73         & 0.21        \\ [2.5mm]
                    $\vartheta_{3}$    & 1         & 2         & 3         & 5         & 4         & 6          & 7         & 9         & 8         & 10         \\
                };

            \draw[line width=0.15mm, black] let \p1 = (O-1-2.north west) in (\x1,\y1 + 1mm) to (\x1,\y1 + 4mm);
            \draw[line width=0.15mm, black] let \p1 = (O-1-4.north east) in (\x1,\y1 + 1mm) to (\x1,\y1 + 4mm);
            \draw[line width=0.15mm, black] let \p1 = (O-1-7.north east) in (\x1,\y1 + 1mm) to (\x1,\y1 + 4mm);
            \draw[line width=0.15mm, black] let \p1 = (O-1-11.north east) in (\x1,\y1 + 1mm) to (\x1,\y1 + 4mm);

            \draw[dashed, colorw_1] let \p1 = (O-1-2.north west), \p2 = (O-1-4.north east) in (\x1,\y1 + 2.5mm) to (\x2,\y2 + 2.5mm);
            \draw[dashed, colorw_2] let \p1 = (O-1-5.north west), \p2 = (O-1-7.north east) in (\x1,\y1 + 2.5mm) to (\x2,\y2 + 2.5mm);
            \draw[dashed, colorw_4] let \p1 = (O-1-8.north west), \p2 = (O-1-11.north east) in (\x1,\y1 + 2.5mm) to (\x2,\y2 + 2.5mm);

            %\foreach\x in{2,...,11}{\draw[my arrow] (O-2-\x) to (O-3-\x);}

            %\coordinate[label=above:$J_1$] (null) at (-2.8,1.25);
            %\coordinate[label=above:$J_2$] (null) at (0.05,1.25);
            %\coordinate[label=above:$J_3$] (null) at (3.15,1.25);

            \end{pgflowlevelscope}
        \end{tikzpicture}
```

I would like to add a label between each of the colored dashed lines, e.g., the green dashed line shown in Figure 1.

How could I add a label centered and overlapping the line with a white background? e.g., the *c* in the middle of the arrow shown in Figure 2.

### Figure 1

[image]

### Figure 2

[image]

Comment: from fragment of code and provided images is not clear what is your problem. ˙it might be, that you looking for `\node (n1)  {B}; \node (n2) [right=of n1] {B}; \draw[dashed] (n1) -- node[fill=white] {c}  (n2);` for better help please provide a small but comlete document (mwe) which will show what you try so far.

Comment: Considering the piece of code that I provided. How could u add a label in between (\x1,\y1 + 2.5mm) and (\x2,\y2 + 2.5mm)?

Comment: as i show in my comment. please be so kind and provide mwe. then it will be easy to show you how to do this.

Comment: Just added the entire code.

Comment: your code can not be complete and can't be compiled. please add document preamble probably there are definitions for used commands in code.

Comment: Probably just the custom colors. I just added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i guess, that you like to obtain something like this:

[image]

actually i rewrite your code snippet from scratch ... (i must confess, that not understand the most of your code). if in this i miss something i'm sure that this will not make troubles to you.

```
\documentclass[border=3.141529mm, tikz, 11pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, matrix, positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 1ex,
       inner ysep = 3mm,
       lbl/.style = {fill=white, inner ysep=0pt, text=black, font=\footnotesize}
    ]
\matrix (m1)    [matrix of nodes,
                 nodes = {rectangle, draw,
                          inner ysep=0pt, minimum width=2.5em, minimum height=4ex},
                 column sep = -\pgflinewidth,
                 row sep = 2ex
                ]
{
1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & 6     & 7     & 8     & 9     & 10    \\
0.12  & 0.89  & 0.38  & 0.96  & 0.43  & 0.66  & 0.49  & 0.81  & 0.73  & 0.21  \\
1     & 2     & 3     & 5     & 4     & 6     & 7     & 9     & 8     & 10    \\
};
\node[left=of m1-1-1] {$V$};
\node[left=of m1-2-1] {$\widetilde{\varphi}_3$};
\node[left=of m1-3-1] {$\varphi_3$};

\path[|<->,draw=blue, dashed]  
(m1.north -| m1-1-1.north west) -- node[lbl] {label 1} (m1.north -| m1-1-4.north west);
\path[|<->,draw=red,  dashed]  
(m1.north -| m1-1-4.north west) -- node[lbl] {label 2} (m1.north -| m1-1-7.north west);
\path[|<->|,draw=teal, dashed] 
(m1.north -| m1-1-7.north west) -- node[lbl] {label 3} (m1.north -| m1-1-10.north east);
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**edit:**
code snippets below now consider your comment. added is `arrows.meta` library and redefined arrows heads.

instead of nodes you can use edge labels from `tikz` library `quotes`. in this case you need to add this library in preamble, define style for edge labels

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 1ex,
       inner ysep = 2mm,
every edge quotes/.style = {fill=white, inner ysep=0pt, anchor=center,
                           text=black, font=\footnotesize},
        arr/.style = {{Bar[width=2.4mm,black]Straight Barb[black]}-%
                      {Straight Barb[black]Bar[width=2.4mm,black]},
                      dashed, thin,
                      shorten < = -0.5\pgflinewidth, shorten > = -0.5\pgflinewidth}
    ]
```

and adopt code for arrows as follows:

```
\path[arr]  
(m1.north -| m1-1-1.north west) edge ["label 1",blue] (m1.north -| m1-1-4.north west)
(m1.north -| m1-1-4.north west) edge ["label 2",red]  (m1.north -| m1-1-7.north west)
(m1.north -| m1-1-7.north west) edge ["label 3",teal] (m1.north -| m1-1-10.north east);
```

[image]

Comment: It works fine. Thank for your hard work and attention. The only problem here is the | in the edges of each arrow is in the color of the arrow. Not a big deal!

Comment: this can be solved by draw vertical lines separately or looks to `arrows.meta` if it can help (for latter i will look late evening).

Comment: @WillEnsaba, i update answer. now vertical bars are in black.